# GridView Search based on the Key Value pair in the URL

Tags: .net, gridview

I'm sending a Key-Value pair with the Target URL. Based on this Key-Value Pair, I would like to search the GridView present in the Target Page. Can somebody please help me out with it?

The Target Page contains a GridView with Columns "JobNo", "Customer", "JobDate".

I'm sending the Key-Value pair for JobNo as below in the Target URL,

http://localhost:1637/Website1/Customer.aspx?JobNo=1234

So when this URL loads, it should search and present me the GridView with only information for JobNo=1234

Comment: If you can modify the datasource of the gridview in the target page, then can you try binding it after filtering the datasource with the JobNo. This has to be done in the page_load of the target page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you. I'm new to .Net. Can you please explain me again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have posted an answer. The grid in the target page must be a bound to a collection. This collection should be filtered using the jobno.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I'm getting an error for that. Can you please look at it once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page_load event execute the following code:

```
YourGridView.DataSource = ((DataTable)(YourGridView.DataSource)).Select("JobNo = '" + Request.QueryString["JobNo"] + "' ").CopyToDataTable();
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

This will take the current GridView DataSource, parse to DataTable then filter from it, then bind the result of the filtering to the GridView again.

Answer (score 0):

In the target page_load event, 
use

```
grid.DataSource = yourDataSource.Select(item => item.JobNo == Request.QueryString["JobNo"]);
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I get this error 

system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource does not contain a definition for SELECT

By the way, my snippet was like this

GridView1.DataSource = ObjectDataSource3.Select(Items => Items.JobNo == Request.QueryString["JobNo"]);
GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: The basic idea would be to filter the DataSource or the collection 'ObjectDataSource3' looking for your JobNo. Once you do that, bind the grid and you would get the result. Could you tell me the type for ObjectDataSource3?